# Restricting file upload if image isn't attached

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, javabeans, multipartform-data

I have a jsf form that takes an email address, brief description, and image from the user.  The else statement below is completely ignored when file==null. If a picture isn't uploaded I want an error telling the user they have to upload a image. How do I accomplish this?

```
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

 private UploadedFile file;

   public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
   }




   public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
   }

  public String upload() {


    if (file!=null ) {
        try {
            System.out.println(file.getFileName());
            InputStream fin2 = file.getInputstream();
            Connection con = DataConnect.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("insert into     PICTURE_TABLE (EMAIL_ADDRESS,PRICE,ITEM_DESC,PICTURES,DATE) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            pre.setString(1, email);

            pre.setString(2, price);
            pre.setString(3,itemDesc);

            pre.setBinaryStream(4, fin2, file.getSize());
            pre.setString(5,time);
            pre.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Inserting Successfully!");




       }


        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception-File Upload." + e.getMessage());
         return "imageFail";

        }
    }
    else{
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select image!!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
```

this is the jsf tag I'm using.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Is it a `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">`? Just set `required="true"` attribute?

Comment: Hi @BalusC I tried that but it's still uploading without the user attaching an image    `<p:fileUpload value="#{uploadImage.file}" mode="simple" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" auto="true" required="true" />`